# Extra cell being added to last row in UICollection View

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

This is my UICollectionView code:

```
  extension UserFeed: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    resizeCollectionView()
    return feeds.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    userFeedDelegate?.didSelectFeed(feeds[indexPath.row])
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: UserFeedCollectionViewCell.kCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UserFeedCollectionViewCell
    print(indexPath.row)
    cell.setup(feeds[indexPath.row])
    return cell
  }

}
```

An here is the setup for my collection view

```
    feedLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    feedLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
    feedLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    feedLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    feedLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

In this instance the feeds.count is 2 and 2 cells being created by the amount of indexPath.row being printed: 0,1

However in the output 4 cells are being displayed with the last to be uninstantiated versions of the custom UICollectionView Cell type. If it helps I only saw this extra cells after adding scrolling to my view.

[image]

Thanks!

Edit:

My resize collection view function:

```
  fileprivate func resizeCollectionView() {
    let height:CGFloat = CGFloat(Int(ceil(Double(feeds.count)/2))) * size
    frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: height)
    userFeedDelegate?.didChangedCollectionHeight()
  }
```

Comment: There is problem with resizeCollectionView try to do that in cellForItemAt indexPath

Comment: I tried that but instead now it does not load anything at all. I also added my resize collection function

Comment: Did you set the `numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView)` to `1` ?